# Flask: Implement URL Versioning with OpenAPI

Tags: python, flask, version, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to implement OpenAPI URL versioning in a Python Flask application, but I'm facing some difficulties. My goal is to achieve the following:

1. Have a SwaggerUI interface that includes a dropdown menu to select different API versions. Something similar like this (Image taken from Google):
   [image: Swagger image taken from Google Images]
2. When a user accesses http://localhost:8080/, the Swagger documentation should load the default API version, which is http://localhost:8080/v1
3. User should be able to test the url http://localhost:8080/v1 or http://localhost:8080/v2 in Postman

Here's what I've done so far:

***Directory structure***

```
 |-BasicAPIVersioning
 | |-.gitignore
 | |-env.yml
 | |-api_versions
 | | |-app.py
 | | |-v1
 | | | |-swagger_v1.json
 | | | |-__init__.py
 | | | |-api.py
 | |-README.md
```

***app.py***

```
# Import libraries
from v1.api import v1_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

authorizations = {
    'apikey': {
        'type':'apiKey',
        'in':'header',
        'name':'Authorization'
    }
} 

api = Api(app, authorizations=authorizations, version='2.0', title='APIs', description='Sample API')

# Register the blueprints with the Flask application
app.register_blueprint(v1_blueprint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = settings.host, port=settings.port)
```

***api.py***

```
# Import libraries
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, Blueprint
from flask_restx import Resource, Api, fields
from flask_cors import CORS  
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest

authorizations = {
    'apikey': {
        'type':'apiKey',
        'in':'header',
        'name':'Authorization'
    }
}

# Create separate blueprints for each version
v1_blueprint = Blueprint('v1', __name__, url_prefix='/v1')
api = Api(v1_blueprint, authorizations=authorizations)

parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('Authorization', location='headers', required=True)

@v1_blueprint.route('/basic')
class TaskReturn(Resource):
    @api.expect(model)
    @api.doc(security = 'apikey')
    @token_required
    def post(self):

        request_data = request.json
        request_data["status"] = "Verified"
        return jsonify(response)
```

***swagger_v1.json***

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
      "title": "API Test",
      "version": "V1"
    },
    "servers": [
      {
        "url": "/v1"
      }
    ],
    "components": {
      "securitySchemes": {
        "jwtAuth": {
          "type": "apiKey",
          "name": "Authorization",
          "in": "header",
          "description": "JWT Token in the 'Authorization' header using the Bearer scheme."
        }
      },
      "schemas": {
        "APIRequest": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "parameter1": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "123"
            },
            "parameter2": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "abc"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "parameter1",
            "parameter2"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "paths": {
      "/basic": {
        "post": {
          "summary": "Sample API",
          "description": "This is a sample API",
          "requestBody": {
            "description": "The request body",
            "required": true,
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/APIRequest"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "success"
            },
            "400": {
              "description": "No results found"
            },
            "401": {
              "description": "Authentication Error"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "security": [
      {
        "jwtAuth": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've gone through several articles, but I'm still struggling to understand how to connect these three files in my Python Flask application. I'm confused about how to ensure that the API definition running at http://localhost:8080/v1 follows the template provided in the `swagger_v1.json` file. Any suggestion or guidance would be really helpful!